# How does the command for installing RVM work?

Tags: command-line, bash

A newbie question.. I was installing [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) (a tool to manage [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) versions). The command for it is:

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

I know a little bit that the `<` is a command redirection operator (correct?).

Then, why is the second `<` needed (what does it do)?

Comment: This really isn't a newbie question; it's quite advanced. Good for you for being curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns a string into the file descriptor for the output of the bash script that it represents. This might be confusing, here's an example

if you type `echo <(ls)` it will open a new file descriptor, the name of which is substituted. So the command might turn into say `echo /dev/fd/63`.

A program that expects a file can now read the output of the command without having to accept stdin.

```
$ my_program ls
Error: 'ls': No such file or directory.
$ my_program <(ls)
my_program was called with the argument /dev/fd/63
bin dev etc ...
```

Many Linux program will, if not provided with a source of input, wait for standard input. Because standard output can be piped to standard input with the "| " operator, you can then use say `ls | grep hello`. This only works because grep would've waited for input anway, if it'd expected a file name to open and read to get its data, the pipe operator doesn't work. This is why you need <(...).

I hope this is intelligible. :-)

Together with the < operator to redirect the output of a file to a programs reading of stdin, this makes for the following *meaning*:

Bash: read the output from this file, which is created from the output of this command.

Clarifications:

- standard input: a "file" (not really, but in linux everything acts like a file) that, when read, magically contains what you've typed
- standard output: a "file" that, when written to, will be printed to the virtual terminal
- operator (i.e. `<` or `<()`): Same as in regular maths, expressions of operators and operands will be evaluated and substituted. 3+2*3 turns into 5*3 turns into 15. It's the same in the bash language.

A nice example to emphasize Roger's point is this expression:

```
if [ -f my_condition ] then something fi
```

Here the contents of the brackets will be evaluated as a conditional statement, i.e. if my_condition is true, then do something. But: `[` is actually just an alias of the program `test`, which, when called with the parameter -f, will check if a file exists.

Comment: the way it is posted in the question, it will feed the output from the curl command into the input of bash, whereas `bash | curl http://...` will do it the other way around. Did you mean `curl http://... | bash` ? That would work in this case.

Comment: That's what I meant of course, well spotted. I'm still a bit tired. :-)

Comment: Thanks! A lot to chew on, i will definitely read more. Btw, is there a "name" for this `<()` operator?

Comment: Oh, got it: `3.5.6 Process Substitution`

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Stefano's point, the second < isn't just a <, it's actually <()

You may already be familiar with a similar construct, $() which produces a string that is the result of the command within it. So:

```
$ which bash # echo the path to bash
/bin/bash
$ ldd $(which bash) # return which libraries bash is linked to
...
```

After the string substitution this is equivalent to

```
ldd /bin/bash
```

As Stefano says, <() does a very similar thing but instead returns a file descriptor.

You can find the bash documentation in `man bash`. As it's a huge man page, you can search (press `/`) for `<\(` (you need to escape the open bracket - searching for `<(` won't work).